# Unable to make GCP bucket public

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to make a bucket in Google Cloud Storage public, but I'm receiving this error:

```
Error
Sorry, there’s a problem. If you entered information, check it and try again. Otherwise, the problem might clear up on its own, so check back later.

Tracking Number: 8176737072451350548

Send feedback
```

I'm sending permission to allUsers to the role StorageObjectViewer. I'm doing this direct by the platform

Comment: Looking here ... https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl ... it seems a command such as gsutil acl ch -u AllUsers:R gs://example-bucket might work.

Answer (score 0):

On GCP uses the shell command inside your project:

```
$ gsutil defacl set public-read gs://your-bucket-name
```

after use:

```
$ gsutil ls -L -b gs://your-bucket-name
```

to see the ACL configuration of your bucket.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-upload-objects-to-cloud-storage/#0